# aticonfig no supported adapters detected

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, ati

I want to install redhat or centos on computer,but when the linux system run on the computer,
the electric fan is run fast and hot,then I try to install ati driver to slove the problem,every time I install the rpm of driver,but the last step,**"aticonfig --initial"** it doesn't work,the  system point out **"aticonfig no supported adapters detected  "**,How cai I solve the problem ?Thank you very much.